# Toggle Command Button Value from Ascending to Descending

Tags: visualforce, actionsupport, commandbutton, commandlink, apexactionfunction

I have a command link Ascending. If I click on the link, immediately, the value of the button/link should change to Descending.

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!Asc}" value="Ascending" reRender="block" status="waitMsg" />
```

To implement this, Im thinking of adding another commandLink with value 'Descending'. And after I click on Ascending, the Asc command button should disappear and the Descending button should appear and vice versa. How to do this? Any ideas?

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!Desc}" value="Descending" reRender="block" status="waitMsg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Boolean properties to your controller called e.g. `showAscending` and `showDescending` (that are set appropriately when the controller is constructed and by the `Asc` and `Desc` methods) and then use those to control the rendering of the links:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!Asc}" ... rendered="{!showAscending}" />
<apex:commandLink action="{!Desc}" ... rendered="{!showDescending}" />
```