# Delete custom records on visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I just started to learn Sales Force and Visual Force. I'm making employee search and delete page for my practice. My question is How to make the delete button appear and function on the left side of the record. I'm so sorry that my English skill is very poor.

This is my VF page

```
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="EmployeeDeletePage">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!info.Employee_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!info.Employee_Mailaddress__c}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="in">
                <apex:column value="{!in.Employee_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!in.Employee_Mailaddress__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>            
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is my Controller

```
    public Employee_Management__c info { get;set; }
    
    public List<Employee_Management__c> results { get;set; }
    
    public string SelectedEmployeeId { get;set; }
    
    public EmployeeDelete1Controller(){
        results = new List<Employee_Management__c>();
        info = new Employee_Management__c();
    }
        
    public PageReference search(){
        String strSoqlQuery1;
        string strEmployeeNamec;
        
        String strSoqlQuery2;
        string strEmployeeMailaddressc;

        IF (!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c)) {
            strEmployeeNamec = info.Employee_Name__c;
            strSoqlQuery1 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c where Id != null and Employee_Name__c = \'' + strEmployeeNamec + '\'';
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery1);
        }
                
        else if (!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Mailaddress__c)) {
            strEmployeeMailaddressc = info.Employee_Mailaddress__c;
            strSoqlQuery2 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c where Id != null and Employee_Mailaddress__c = \'' + strEmployeeMailaddressc + '\'';
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery2);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page block table, add a column for this:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Actions">
  <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteRecord}" value="Delete">
    <apex:param name="employeeId" assignTo="{!employeeIdToDelete}" value="{!in.Id}" />
  </apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>
```

And in your apex:

```
public transient Id employeeIdToDelete;
public void deleteRecord() {
  delete [SELECT Id FROM Employee_Management__c WHERE Id = :employeeIdToDelete];
  search(); // Reload results
}
```

Note that apex:commandButton does not support parameters, so if you want to use a button, you would need a more complicated setup involving an apex:commandButton and apex:actionFunction instead, or a more complicated setup involving a wrapper (which I demonstrate in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/113456/2984)).

Comment: I just solve my Issue, Thanks you sfdcfox!